# May a 3 sided pyramid (almost) be used as a succah?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, architecture-design, schach

Talmud succah states that a succah must have a minimum of 3 sides. Can a person build a 3-sided pyramid, but rather than a "full" pyramid, where all the sides meet at the same point at the top, let's say, there's a small triangle (say 9 square inches in area) on top and schach is placed there. Is this permitted?

Two possible problems, perhaps:

- Do all the walls need to be perpendicular to the ground?
- What is the minimal area required for a valid roof for the succah? Is 9 sq. in. too small?

Comment: Well the minimum area of a sukkah is large enough for someone to fit his head and most of his body inside and the gemara in Sukkah (or maybe just Rashi, I don't remember) repeatedly mentions that the _skhakh_ basically _is_ the sukkah. So I would imagine that the _skhakh_ must be at least that area.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara in Sukkah (I believe in the daf is in the high-teens) discusses a halachic principle of *dofen akuma* (a bent wall). The case is slightly different from your scenario, but I think still applies. The Gemara's case is when there is a bit of roofing that is not kosher for *skhakh* separating the walls and the kosher *skhakh*. Normally the maximum distance between a wall and the *skhakh* is 3 *tefachim*. If the distance is greater than that, the *sukkah* is *pasul*. But if you have some non-kosher roofing material connecting the wall to the *skhakh*, it is considered as if that roofing material is actually part of the wall (so the wall goes vertically up to the roof and then horizontally to the *skhakh*).

In that case, the *sukkah* is kosher; however, those inhabiting the *sukkah* must sit directly under the kosher *skhakh*. One does not fulfill his obligation for dwelling in the *sukkah* sitting under the "bent wall."

I think this clearly applies to your case where we don't have to go through any mental gymnastics to explain that the invalid roofing is actually a horizontal wall. In your case, we are talking about *actually sitting under a wall* and the *halakha* should apply the same. The *sukkah* is kosher, but one must be careful to sit under the actual *skhakh*.

As far as the minimal area, the gemara says on daf 2b that the minimal area of a *sukkah* is large enough to fit one's head and most of his body. Rashi repeatedly mentions that a *sukkah* is called a *sukkah* in the first place because of the *skhakh* and therefore implies that the *skhakh* is the *ikkar* of the *sukkah*. Therefore, I think that the minimum area of the *skhakh* would be large enough to fit one's head and most of his body.

Answer (score 0):

If you can fit a 7x7x10 Succah inside the walls it should be fine. This is similar to the round Succah mentioned in Succah 7b, which has this requirement. And it is also a case of slanted roof which was discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64011/does-a-succah-require-a-definitive-roof).