# Does a succah require a definitive roof?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, architecture-design, schach

Let's say your entire succah is made from very large bamboo poles, which are eligible to be used for schach. You decide to make a true 3-sided pyramid, where you lay the poles at an angle making a 3-sided base, but all the poles meet at a point on top. Essentially, there is no flat "roof", as your walls, in a sense, form the roof, and, as said, everything is shcach. Is this OK?

Comment: IIRC, an extremely similar case is discussed in the _mishna_, but with two sloped walls and one straight one.

Comment: According to the answer in http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64010/may-a-3-sided-pyramid-almost-be-used-as-a-succah/64013#64013 no.

Comment: @sabbahillel how do you get that from that answer?

Comment: @Daniel succah **must** have a flat roof and one must sit under that roof. The pointed roof you mention is an extreme case.

Comment: @sabbahillel I never said the roof must be flat. In this question the walls are made of kosher _skhakh_. In that question they (presumably) are not.

Comment: @Daniel that is the point. If it is like a teepee and has no roof, it is pasul no matter what the walls are made of (even schach material.

Comment: @sabbahillel I don't know how you got that from my answer on the other question but note that Danny Schoemann shows that at least the Rema seems to permit such a sukkah.

Comment: @Daniel No the remo says that one may sleep under the walls (made from schach material) **if** there is enough kosher schach (as a flat roof) to make the succa kosher. וְצָרִיךְ שֶׁיִּהְיֶה בָּהּ ז' טְפָחִים עַל ז' בְּגֹבַהּ י' טְפָחִים

Comment: @sabbahillel unless the walls are very short, that will always be true.

Comment: @Daniel The question as asked talked about a succah that does **not** have the minimum flat roof (comes to a point).

Comment: @sabbahillel where does the Rema say the roof must be flat. He seems to be arguing on the Mechaber here

Comment: @Daniel וְצָרִיךְ שֶׁיִּהְיֶה בָּהּ ז' טְפָחִים עַל ז' בְּגֹבַהּ י' טְפָחִים speaks of the roof (the flat part of the schach) The Remo does not argue but speaks only of sleeping. Eating must be under the flat roof. The illustrated mishnayis shows this  explicitly. (that a point is pasul)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mechaber in [סימן תרלא - סכה שחמתה מרבה מצלתה ויתר דיני הסכך](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_36.html#HtmpReportNum0006_L2) says that if there's no roof then it's invalid, unless there's a square-Tefach of [horizontal] roof, or that there's a Tefach of vertical walls between the ground and the slanted wall-roof:

The Remo however,  permits such a Sukka, on condition that there's the minimal 7x7 Tefachim area at a height of 10 Tefachim.

He adds that if the entire wall is made of valid S'chach, one may even sleep under the *walls* - i.e. the part below 10 Tefachim high.

The entire Se'if says:

> **י:** סֻכָּה שֶׁאֵין לָהּ גַּג, כְּגוֹן שֶׁהָיוּ רָאשֵׁי הַדְּפָנוֹת דְּבוּקוֹת זוֹ בְּזוֹ כְּמִין צְרִיף, אוֹ שֶׁסָמַךְ רֹאשׁ הַדֹּפֶן שֶׁל סֻכָּה לַכֹּתֶל, פְּסוּלָה; וְאִם הָיָה לָהּ גַּג, אֲפִלּוּ טֶפַח, אוֹ שֶׁהִגְבִּיהַּ הַדֹּפֶן הַסָמוּךְ לַכֹּתֶל מִן הַקַּרְקַע טֶפַח, הֲרֵי זוֹ כְּשֵׁרָה. **הגה**: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁהַטֶּפַח לֹא תִּהְיֶה אֲוִיר, רַק מִן הַדֹּפֶן אוֹ הַסְּכָךְ <sub>(הָרֹא''שׁ בְּשֵׁם ר''י וְהרה''מ פ''ד)</sub> וְצָרִיךְ שֶׁיִּהְיֶה בָּהּ  ז' טְפָחִים עַל ז' בְּגֹבַהּ י' טְפָחִים <sub>(טוּר)</sub>. גַּם צָרִיךְ שֶׁיִּהְיוּ הַדְּפָנוֹת לְאַחַר שֶׁהֵם גְּבוֹהִים עֲשָׂרָה עֲשׂוּיוֹת מִדָּבָר שֶׁמְּסַכְּכִין בָּהֶם, דְּהָא הֵם הַסְּכָךְ <sub>(רַ''ן ספ''ק דְּסֻכָּה)</sub>. **וְאִם כָּל הַדְּפָנוֹת מִדָּבָר שֶׁמְּסַכְּכִין בָּהֶם, מֻתָּר לִישַׁן אֲפִלּוּ תַּחַת הַדְּפָנוֹת** <sub>(ס''ח בְּפֵרוּשׁ רַבֵּנוּ יְרוּחָם נ''א נ''ח)</sub>.‏

Comment: You have a typo in your first sentence. You say "permits" but quote the Mechaber that it is pasul and the Remo allows **sleeping** under the walls only if there is a minimum amount of space under the roof to make it a valid succa.

Comment: @sabbahillel - I edited the answer - hopefully closer to the original, now.

Comment: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁהַטֶּפַח לֹא תִּהְיֶה אֲוִיר, רַק מִן הַדֹּפֶן אוֹ הַסְּכָךְ means that hte space between the walls and the kosher schach must be a tefach or less and not empty space. וְצָרִיךְ שֶׁיִּהְיֶה בָּהּ ז' טְפָחִים עַל ז' means that the kosher schach part (the flat roof)  must be 7x7

Comment: @sabbahillel (1): "a tefach or less"??? You surely mean  a tefach or MORE! As the mechaber wrote אֲפִלּוּ טֶפַח. And (2) "the flat roof must be 7x7" - I don't think so - if you add the next words בְּגֹבַהּ י' טְפָחִים then it reads like I wrote; at a height of 10, you need a 7x7 area.